# Why is gulp so slow on windows machine?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Gulp runs 4 times slower for me on windows than on a mac. I have added the gulp file as well as the command-line output below.The gulpfile is pretty simple.

Here is the command-line output:

```
$ gulp
    [14:00:06] Using gulpfile c:\gulpSample\gulpfile.js
    [14:00:06] Starting 'scripts'...
    [14:00:07] Finished 'scripts' after 26 ms
    [14:00:07] Starting 'watch'...
    [14:00:07] Finished 'watch' after 30 ms
    [14:00:07] Starting 'default'...
    [14:00:07] Finished 'default' after 23 μs
```

The times on a mac are usually 4 times faster

Here's the gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
//var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

//scripts Task
//uglifies

function errorLog(error){
    console.error.bind(error);
    this.emit('end');
}

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src('js/*.js')
    //.pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});


    //Watch Task
    gulp.task('watch', function(){
        gulp.watch('js/*.js',['scripts']);
        gulp.watch('scss/*.scss',['styles']);
    });

    gulp.task('default',['scripts','watch']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The script task time execution is incorrect, as you need to call back to gulp so that it can properly sink the stream. That execution time you posted is only how long gulp took to initialise the task. To fix it, you need to *return* the stream:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
    //.pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

This should give you a better idea of how long the tasks are actually taking to complete.